# A textual month could not be found ,Trailing data Carbon - laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I did try different ways, but I have not get the proper time format.

```
$news->created_at = Carbon::parse($news->created_at)->format('M, d, Y');

$news->created_at = date('d M Y',strtotime($news->created_at))

$news->created_at = date('d M Y',$news->created_at)

$news->created_at = Carbon::createFromFormat("d M Y",strtotime($news->created_at));

$news->created_at = $news->created_at->format('M, d, Y');
```

And the **errors** are,

> Unexpected data found
>   The separation symbol could not be found
>   InvalidArgumentException

`Carbon.php: 910`

dd($news->created_at);

```
Carbon @1550035143 {#361 ▼
  date: 2019-02-13 05:19:03.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

Comment: How does the value looks like in your DB?

Comment: Whats is the initial format of created_at and how would you like to format it later?

Comment: @Ruub Please check the question

Comment: I might be wrong, but isnt this already an carbon instance? I think you can do: `$news->created_at = $news->created_at->format('M, d, Y');`

Comment: @Ruub returns this **Unexpected data found The separation symbol could not be found Data missing**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a Carbon instance in your `$news->created_at` field, because Eloquent models consider the [`created_at` and `updated_at` columns  as timestamps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models) by default and automatically convert them to `Carbon` instances. So you just need to use the [`format`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) method from Carbon:

```php
$news->created_at->format('d M Y');
```

However, when you try to reassign a string as the value of `created_at` on the model instance, it conflicts with Laravel's internal mutator that tries to convert any value assigned to a date field from a Carbon instance into a string.

You could set `public $timestamps = false;` in your `News` model and then use strings throughout your app when handling model timestamps, but that seems like a hack more than a solution, because you'd be giving up on all the benefits that Carbon offers.

You also could also do this by handling timestamps at serialization time, something like this:

```php
return collect($news->makeHidden(['created_at']))->merge([
    'created_at' => $news->created_at->format('d M Y')
]);
```

The above code will hide the columns passed to `makeHidden` from the serialization process. Then you could merge the formatted values for the hidden columns into your response.

Comment: returns this **Unexpected data found The separation symbol could not be found Data missing**

Comment: in the same line Carbon.php : 910

Comment: Are you getting the error from the line assigning the date `$news->created_at = $news->created_at->format('d M Y');` or somewhere else?

Comment: Also please explain in more detail what are you trying to achieve and what's the purpose of changing the value of the `created_at` field? Is it sent to the client and needs to be formatted in a specific way for it to be displayed? More context can help us offer better solutions.

Comment: I am Developing API, front-end developers need the Date in _1 Feb 2019_ format.