# Two different time format on same model created_at column

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am developing API in Laravel, I faced some [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690089/a-textual-month-could-not-be-found-trailing-data-carbon-laravel) date format and then solved by introducing a function in the model file,

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date){
    return date('M d, Y h:i:s A',strtotime($date));
}
```

Now in another API, I wanna send created_at format `(d M Y)`. Started to face the same issue again in Carbon.php:910.

Comment: Try to rename the mutator method to something else like `getFormatedCreatedAtAttribute` because I am guessing it clashes with the actual created_at attribute

Comment: If you want a default format you can set in the model the property: `protected $dateFormat = 'd M Y';`

Comment: @ka_lin I want it in two different formats.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Date Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

use inside your model

```
protected $dates = [
    'seen_at',
];
```

and then create a mutator for that date

```
public function getSeenAtAttribute()
{
    return date('M d, Y h:i:s A',strtotime($this->created_at));
}
```